How do I align elements in a UWP Windows 10 Mobile app?
I have this simple layout in a Windows 10 Mobile app:
<Page
x:Class="Clock_Mobile.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Clock_Mobile"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" FontFamily="Schnaubelt">

<Grid>
    <Ellipse UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Fill="#FFEBEBEB"/>
    <Ellipse UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Fill="#FFFF9900"/>
    <Ellipse UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="8" Fill="Black"/>
</Grid>

And it looks like this:

The circles are not properly aligned, even though the window width and height are even numbers.
How do I make them align? I'm also ok to use another Control and Graphics API like Graphics2D in Java, but finding documentation right now for this deprecated platform is very hard.

Yes; it "should" work. You can add a Margin to the Orange (and maybe Black) circle to move it right (Margin=(1,0,0,0)). Try with and without "UseLayoutRounding". It's quite a small graphic (icons are usually at least 32x32); and it's a "circle"; and trying to snap to pixels in this case, I'm not sure which pixels it will align. Points in UWP are doubles ... aligning does not always yield a desirable result; especially when animating over small distances.

With circles that have diameters of even pixels, you can't come up with a "true" center point pixel either to align everything on; if that's the formula being used.

thanks, It worked like this: first circle, no change, 2nd and 3rd circles, 1px smaller diameter with 1px top and left margin

@GerrySchmitz it doesn't make any sense, if all the circles have either even or odd diameters at the same time then you should be able to pixel perfect align them.
